# Is it necessary to load SqlServerTypes when using Microsoft ReportViewerControl v14?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, webforms, reportviewer

After I installed the report viewer control v14 package via nuget, a folder “SqlServerTypes” is created in my project root directory.
There is a readme.htm file and it suggests adding a piece SqlServerTypes loading code into the web form page which has report viewer control.

But I found even without this SqlServerTypes loading code, the report viewer still works well.

I wonder if it is necessary to add this loading code.

Thanks.

---

************* The readme.htm *************

Action required to load native assemblies
To deploy an application that uses spatial data types to a machine that does not have 'System CLR Types for SQL Server' installed you also need to deploy the native assembly SqlServerSpatial140.dll. Both x86 (32 bit) and x64 (64 bit) versions of this assembly have been added to your project under the SqlServerTypes\x86 and SqlServerTypes\x64 subdirectories. The native assembly msvcr120.dll is also included in case the C++ runtime is not installed.

You need to add code to load the correct one of these assemblies at runtime (depending on the current architecture).

ASP.NET Web Sites
For ASP.NET Web Sites, add the following block of code to the code behind file of the Web Form where you have added Report Viewer Control:

Default.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        static bool _isSqlTypesLoaded = false;

    public _Default()
    {
        if (!_isSqlTypesLoaded)
        {
            SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~"));
            _isSqlTypesLoaded = true;
        }

    }
    }
```

---

**** The SqlServerTypes folder ******

```
[SqlServerTypes]
Loader.cs 
readme.htm

[SqlServerTypes\x64]
msvcr120.dll
SqlServerSpatial140.dll

[SqlServerTypes\x86]
msvcr120.dll
SqlServerSpatial140.dll
```

---

******** Nuget package *********

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms

Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms -Version 140.1000.523

Comment: the standalone setup of the microsoft report viewer runtime 12 and up also requires this pre-installed, at least on some versions of windows. So it is at least consistent behavior that the nuget package has the same dependency.

Comment: I noticed this as well when I recently upgraded to v15. I just went ahead and deleted that directory and when I deployed the upgraded code everything worked fine.